# How to iterate over all files in multiple folders with python

Tags: python, list, directory

I'm trying to iterate over all directories in directory and find all .html files there. So far I've this code:

```
def find_path():
"""

:return: List
"""
paths = []
for filename in os.listdir(DIRECTORY):
    if filename.endswith('.html'):
        fname = os.path.join(DIRECTORY, filename)
        with open(fname, 'r') as f:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(), 'html.parser')
            path = soup.select_one('#tree > li > span').contents[-1]
            paths.append(path)
return paths
```

But it only works if all .html files are in one directory. What I need is to iterate over all .html files in this directory and save it, but for every directory in that directory there are also .html files that I need to have access to. So ideally, I need to open all of these directories in my parent directory and save whatever I need from .html files. Is there a way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: You could use ```os.walk()```

Comment: A recursive glob such as `glob.glob("**/*.html", recursive=True)` should do that out of the box.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi thank you. Could you please explain further? I'm trying to use this but I'm not able to find a working solution using this :X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below sample snippet both #1 or #2 works:

```
import os
path = "."
for (root, dirs, files) in os.walk(path, topdown=True):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".html"):
            print(root+"/"+file)                #1
            print(os.path.join(root+"/"+file))  #2
```

Answer (score 1):

`os.walk()` can help you

```
import os


def find_path(dir_):
    for root, folders, names in os.walk(dir_):
        for name in names:
            if name.endswith(".html"):
                # Your code
                pass
```

Comment: thank you. When I try to do it like this, the "fname" variable I'm creating is giving me full path, and it's giving me an error - No such file or directory: .... But the files are there. Would you know how to resolve this?